# JavaScript cache return value of a function with more than one parameter

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm going through [John Resig's snippets on advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/). On [#19](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#19) he mentions a method to cache the return value of a function. What's the best way to cache the return value of a function that has more than one parameter?

There has to be a much better way than stringify-ing the recieved arguments and using that as the key for the cache object:

```
function $$(selector, el) {
    var cacheKey = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    if ($$.cache[cacheKey]) return $$.cache[cacheKey];

    return ($$.cache[cacheKey] = NodeListToArray( (el || document).querySelectorAll(s) ));
}
$$.cache = {};
```

Comment: Well, what more do you have to give the result an identity?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom hash function that can operate on objects. But hash functions cause collisions and would require significantly more code than your simple example.

Or you could make the cache n-dimensional, where n is the number of arguments. So essentially this:

```
function $$(selector, el) {
    if ($$.cache[selector] && $$.cache[selector][el])
        return $$.cache[cacheKey][el];
    // etc.
```

That assumes that both selector and el are able to be used as object keys. You may need to stringify them in another manner.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider an array element,

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) works with generic platform, so for easy use you must create a function for your use,

Here, `$$.cache[0]` is your easy way after reading the `cachekey`,

If we make thing more easy, we might have security problem later.

I hope this will satisfy your requirement :)